# How to 'make' OpenWhisk Docker Compose in Windows 10?

Tags: openwhisk

I am new to OpenWhisk.

I have windows 10, with Docker for windows installed. I followed the instructions given in the following URL to download the Docker compose from GIT, on my Windows 10 laptop.

This website mentions command 'make quick-start'. I learned from internet that 'make' is a Unix command. I want to understand how I can build this on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it doesn't work on Windows so far. See https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-devtools/issues/119 for more details.